# Alpine APK: Unable to use repository tags when creating a virtual dependency

Tags: alpine-linux, alpine-package-keeper

Due to rather minimalistic wiki/docs for Alpine Package Keeper, I have failed to determine why it appears to refuse repository tags when specifying packages part of a virtual dependency.

The question is, is this by design, and if so, what is the motivation behind this difference?

---

Minimal reproducible example:

```
docker run --rm -it alpine:3.18
echo @v316 https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.16/community >> /etc/apk/repositories
apk add --no-cache --virtual .example librdkafka-dev@v316
```

This produces an **unexpected** error:

```
ERROR: 'librdkafka-dev@v316' is not a valid child dependency, format is name([<>~=]version)
```

No error with:

```
apk add --no-cache librdkafka-dev@v316
```

Comment: Seems related: https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/issues/205

Comment: Considering it was created in 2016 and alleging it is a bug, the perspective looks bleak. In any case, it does appear to describe the same thing.